# How to reset my Towers Of Hanoi game after completeion or other better ways of doing things here

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I am trying to figure out a way to reset the game back to the original array so that the player can start over, it is a towers of hanoi game.  This function maps the board as players select arrMove(board, from, to).  Also looking for any tips on how i can make this better by maybe not having to type out the entire "arrMove(board to from)" or any other tips anyone may have I have been studying Javascript for about 2 month and looking to learn as much as possible

```
var line1 = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
var line2 = new Array();
var line3 = new Array();
var board = [line1, line2, line3];

function arrMove(arr, oldIndex, newIndex) {
  var newBoard = arr.map( function (someVar){
    return someVar.map(function(arr2) {
      return arr2;
    });
  });

  function winAndReset() {
    alert("You have won");
  };

  function arrayEquals(a, b) {
    return Array.isArray(a) &&
      Array.isArray(b) &&
      a.length === b.length &&
      a.every((val, index) => val === b[index]);
  };

  
  function moveRule() {
    newBoard[newIndex].push(newBoard[oldIndex].pop(1));
  };

  if (newBoard[oldIndex][newBoard[oldIndex].length - 1] > newBoard[newIndex][newBoard[newIndex].length - 1] ) {
    alert ("Illegal Move");
  } else {
    moveRule();
  };

  if (arrayEquals(newBoard[1], line1)) {
    winAndReset();
  } else if(arrayEquals(newBoard[2], line1)) {
    winAndReset();
  };

  board  = newBoard;
  console.table(board);


};
```

Comment: `board = [line1, line2, line3]`

Comment: would that mess things up since i have board = newBoard in the function?